# QnAMaker Bot with LUIS Bot merge

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Okay so I have the LUIS Bot to kickoff the conversation in my **Post** method in **MessageController.cs**

```
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new LUISDialog());
```

when the bot detects the None intent it will make a call to the QnA bot and forward the message to it

```
await context.Forward(new QnABot(), Whatever, result.Query, CancellationToken.None);
```

Here's my problem:
When the QnA bot is started, method **MessageReceivedAsync** in **QnAMakerDialog.cs** class is throwing an exception on the parameter
**"IAwaitable<.IMessageActivity> argument"**

**[Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.InvalidTypeException] = {"invalid type: expected Microsoft.Bot.Connector.IMessageActivity, have String"}"**

when trying to access it via --> var message = await argument;

I don't understand what the problem is, I'm typing a simple plain text in the qna bot, and my knowledge base has no problem returning a response when I tried it on the website. I'm not sure what's happening between the time StartAsync is called and MessageReceivedAsync is called that is causing the parameter 'argument' to fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are sending a `string` (`result.Query`) and the `QnAMakerDialog.cs` is expecting an `IMessageActivity`.

Try updating your `context.Forward` call to:

```
var msg = context.MakeMessage();
msg.Text = result.Query;

await context.Forward(new QnABot(), Whatever, msg, CancellationToken.None);
```

Alternatively, you can update the signature of the None intent method to include the original `IMessageActivity`:

```
[LuistIntent("None"))]
public async Task None(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
{
   var msg = await activity;

   await context.Forward(new QnABot(), Whatever, msg, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: you're right, it was the way I was sending the query.
I updated my signature and it works just fine now. Thank you